# Computability for universal quantum turing machines

Tags: quantum-computing, computability, turing-machines, universal-turing-machines

I would like to ask if anyone has any ideas about what a universal quantum turing machine (UQTM) can do as supposed to a classical universal turing machine (UTM) (i.e. quantum computer vs classical computer).

I wonder if a UQTM can solve NP problems as supposed to a UTM. I know that one of the biggest ideas in computability is that giving enough time the slow computer will calculate the samething as the fast computer just with more time. Since a UQTM can solve higher complexity problems (such as solving a molecular system) at faster speeds then a UTM, this doesn't mean for the UTM this is unsolvable.

Therefor, are there problems a UQTM can solve that a UTM cannot and vice-versa?

What about NP problems or non-computable problems?

Comment: Short answers: (i) any QTM can be simulated by a TM so every language decidable by a QTM is decidable by a TM [[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing#Computability)].  (ii) It is not known whether any NP-hard problem can be solved in poly time by a QTM, but some problems (e.g. factoring) that are not known to have poly-time algorithms do have poly-time QTM algorithms [[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing#Complexity)].  Try to find an intro to quantum computing for more details.  This is not a research-level question so will probably be closed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.